# Converting Structure to char* pointer in C

Tags: c, struct, uart, char-pointer

I am having a structure:

```
struct K 
{
  char a[10];
  char b[10];
};
```

I wish to convert this structure to a char* pointer and print the value on Uart. Uart takes char* pointer as input.

My main function looks like:

```
void main()
{
    struct K x= { "Hello","Pollo"};
    struct K *revert;
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char *)&x;
    revert = (struct K *) buffer;
    printf("%s %s", revert->a,revert->b);
}
```

Note: printf() won't work, I am using a UART.

I want to print the buffer value on UART when it is done with converting structure pointer to `char *` pointer. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please do not use `void main`. Take one of the entry points defined in the standard.

Comment: @nvoigt You statement is self-contradictory. Standard defines that entry point can be implementation defined.

Comment: @this You realize that "implementation defined" is a bad thing, right?

Comment: @nvoigt You should call Microsoft( and many, many microcontroller companies, which use void main in they compilers ) and tell them that. Maybe they will hire you. On the other hand, they will most likely ignore your ridiculous statements. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c+microcontroller+%22void+main%28%22&t=ffsb #DontBeIgnorant

Comment: My ridiculous statements lead to working programs that are cross-platform. You may ignore them, but you won't get cross-platform, standard compliant code. It's your choice if you want to aim for less.

Comment: @nvoigt You seem to live in a self imposed bubble. Your arguments are black-and-white thinking, which makes them non-arguments. We live in a very diverse world of computing, where for example, platform centric software clearly thrives.

Comment: @this That's fine. Let them thrive. I don't mind (matter of fact, I'm part of it). But I won't teach non-standard behaviour to newbies. Once they are experts, they can decide that for themselves.

Comment: @nvoigt And we come full circle. Teaching that void main isn't defined by C is incorrect. It may be non-standard, whatever your definition of standard is, but it is definitely implicitly defined by the C Standard. I was tempted to call you out on the "standard" definition before, I will definitely do it the next time.

Comment: @this This is a free site, feel free to do whatever you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach to splitting and recombining the struct elements into a char* string is with the string functions `sprintf` and then `strncpy`. There are many, many ways to do this. Simple pointer arithmetic will do, etc.. But this approach is fairly clean and straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct K 
{
char a[10];
char b[10];
};

int main (void)
{
    char tmp[21] = {0};
    char *buf = tmp;
    struct K x = { "Hello","Pollo"};
    struct K rev = {{0},{0}};

    /* combine x.a & x.b into single string in buf */
    sprintf (buf, "%s%s", x.a, x.b);

    /* print the combined results */
    printf ("\n combined strings: %s\n\n", buf);

    /* get original lenght of x.a & x.b */
    size_t alen = strlen(x.a);
    size_t blen = strlen(x.b);

    /* copy from buf into rev.a & rev.b as required */
    strncpy (rev.a, buf, alen);
    strncpy (rev.b, buf+alen, blen);

    printf (" recombined: rev.a: %s  rev.b: %s\n\n", rev.a, rev.b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct2str

 combined strings: HelloPollo

 recombined: rev.a: Hello  rev.b: Pollo
```

Comment: sprintf() does the miracle. Thanks.